# Does the order of the routes effect which controller is accessed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In my app I have grants and I want the url to be root/grant_id instead of root/grants/grant_id.  I have this in my routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ...
  root                    'static_pages#welcome'
  # get     'home'      =>  'static_pages#home'
  get     'about'       =>  'static_pages#about'
  get     'faq'       =>  'static_pages#faq'
  get     'signup'    =>  'users#new'
  get     'login'     =>  'sessions#new'
  post    'login'     =>  'sessions#create'
  delete  'logout'    =>  'sessions#destroy'  
  get     'dashboard' => 'dashboard#index'


  resources :users do
    resources :projects
      member do
        get 'access_granted'
        put 'access_granted'
        get 'remove_access'
        put 'remove_access'
      end
  end


  resources :profiles
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  resource :request_access, only: [:show, :new, :create]

 resources :grants, :path => '' do
    resources :app_types do
      resources :submissions
    end
  end
  get     'grants'    =>  'grants#index'

  resources :matches

end
```

When I put `resources :matches` below the `resources :grants, :path => '' do` line I get the error "Couldn't find Grant" and I see that request parameters are 
{"controller"=>"grants", "action"=>"show", "id"=>"matches"}.  When I put `resources :matches` above the the grant line everything works fine.  Its almost like something in the grant route isn't closing and is forcing any lines below it to look for the grant controller.  A simple solution is just keeping everything above that line but I'm trying to understand why this is happening.

I also noticed that even though I define the grant#index as grants, when I rake routes I see:

```
 grants GET    /                 grants#index
        GET    /grants(.:format) grants#index
```

So two questions 
1. Is :path => '' the correct way to remove the grants/ part of the url.
2. Why is everything below the grants route getting sent to the grants controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation :

> Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified, so if you have a resources :photos above a get 'photos/poll' the show action's route for the resources line will be matched before the get line. To fix this, move the get line above the resources line so that it is matched first.

So, the problem you're having is that matching grants to "" means your grants INDEX route is /, and your grants SHOW route is /:grant_id, which will match any route. If you want to have this kind of route (which I would advise against), it has got to be at the bottom of the routes file.

You can read more about routing here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html